# How to connect to handheld RFID reader using .Net

Tags: .net, windows-ce, rfid

I am tying to write an application in .Net for a handheld RFID reader on which Windows CE is running. I want to know how do you connect to that reader?

Normally if there is external reader, you simply give its IP and port in your application to connect (either Socket or TcpClient) but in this case the reader is not on a separate machine but both Windows CE and reader are in one handheld device.

So what will be the IP and port in this case? I tried reading its documentation but can't figure out that.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible it's either on a serial port, or implemented as a keyboard wedge. Try opening a text editor and see if tags are typed in. If not, look at reading serial (COM) ports.

There is a SerialPort class for this very need :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you still can connect with IP.
Which reader are you using.
for example - for Motorola RFID handheld device MC 9190Z I found out in the documentation the following code for connecting to the reader (I also saw the same approach here in some post):

```
private void ConnectToReader()
        {
            // Establish connection to the RFID Reader
            string hostname = "157.235.208.20";
            rfid3 = new RFIDReader(hostname, 5084, 10000);
            rfid3.Connect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

1. Manufacturer Developer Kit (DK) (i.e. EMDK for .Net v2.x for Motorola RFID devices)
2. Respective SDKs/DTKs (WM 6 Professional SDK and 6.5 DTK for WM 6.x)
3. Visual Studio (2005 or 2008 depending on requirements)
4. In case you know how to deal with ports and input interfaces try to do your own DLL API and test it deploying the app to your device
5. In case you don't, just follow instructions from the Manufacturer's APIs
6. As user2192280 stated above in order to use that API in your handheld client app you have to code using Motorola EMDK (add Symbol.RFIDn.Device reference to your project):

```cs
string hostname = "localhost" // or NULL or "127.0.0.1";
// use default ports and response time out
int port = 0; 
int period = 0;
RFIDReader reader = new RFIDReader(hostname, port, period);
//To connect reader
reader.Connect();

    /*do whatever you need to do*/

//To disconnect
reader.Disconnect();
```

be sure you are targeting the right .Net CF according to your software.

Hope this may help.